# Wrapping Angular2 app as node module library

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, node-modules

I have a sizable Angular2 app that I want to make available as a node_module. The app is based on [Angular 2 Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) which uses systemjs.  What would be the best approach to allowing this application to be embedded in another angular2 app as a node_module?

Answer (score 0):

You create your application as an NPM package, and submit it to the NPM repository. Then people can install it with:

```
npm install yourPackageName
```

And then import it in their Angular apps with:

```
import {YourModule} from 'yourPackageName'
```

Comment: Yes, thats the goal, given that its an entire ng2 app, is there any special steps needed or just point my package.json to my app.module as the entry point?

Comment: I don't think there are anything much. Check out their docs. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules